# What’s the difference between Process and ProcessStartInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, process

What’s the difference between `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo`? I’ve used both to launch external programs but there has to be a reason there are two ways to do it. Here are two examples.

```
Process notePad = new Process();
notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs";
notePad.Start();
```

and

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are pretty close to the same, both are from the Process class.   And there are actually [4 other overloads to Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) other than what you mentioned, all static.

One is a [static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) way to do it.  It returns the Process object representing the process that is started.    You could for example start a process with a single line of code by using this way.

And the other is a [member method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) way to do it which reuses the current object instead of returning a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Heh.

If you look closely at your code, you will note that they are both using the same classes. The `StartInfo` property in your first example is, unsurprsingly, a `ProcessStartInfo`. In your second example, you call the static `.Start` method *on* the `Process` class.

So what are the differences? Significant. They're different classes. One is for launching processes, one is for saying which process to launch (and lots of other little things, like capturing output, etc). In the first case, you just use the default `ProcessStartInfo` property that the class has.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ProcessStartInfo` is a subset of `Process` if you look at the members of `notePad` variable below

`Process notePad = new Process();`
You will notice that StartInfo has type (or of class) `ProcessStartInfo`
which is why the two initializations are the same
`notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";` Vs `startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";`
Since `Process` is the full class I would think it can do everything  `ProcessStartInfo` can do plus extra But Don't take my word for it I only less than a year experience in .Net