# The difference between ProcessStartInfo and Process in c#

Tags: c#, .net

What is the differences between the using of Process and ProcessStartInfo in this examples :

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
```

compare to this

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
```

However, I cannot use

> proc.Start();

or

> proc.start();

within the second code.

What is the difference? thank you

Comment: `ProcessStartInfo` is what `Process` uses to start a new process.

Comment: [possible duplicate for Whats the difference between Process and ProcessStartInfo in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890310/whats-the-difference-between-process-and-processstartinfo-in-c)

Comment: Please think on this another 5 minutes and you will understand.

Comment: what is different bw asking new question vs asking question which is already exist?

Comment: i am new in c# guys, so i really dont know why i have to write 'startInfo' all over the code like in the first code when i can declare it on the top and simplify my code. I think it is different question...